# How to set up wro4j for sbt with the latest versions of sbt and plugins on windows?

Tags: coffeescript, sbt, scalatra, wro4j

I have downloaded [this example](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/tree/master/2.2/resources/scalatra-coffeescript) and made some changes to resolve errors. Particularly, I have changed `sbt.version` to `0.13.5` in the `build.properties` file, and changed both `scalatra-sbt` and `xsbt-wro4j-plugin`versions to `0.3.5` in the `project/plugins.sbt`.

This modified example does not work even after creating `wro4j` folder manually - command `wro4j` does nothing and after `container:start` `http://localhost:8080/compiled/scripts.js` results in 404.

What else does the plugin need to work with newer versions of sbt and plugins? What is the working version combination for wro4j?

The failing example is in https://github.com/Odomontois/scalatra-coffeescript.

**UPDATE**

Just checked it on linux machine. All have been produced properly. So it looks like windows-only problem.

**UPDATE 2**

After lots of different checks i have investigated that problem somehow is related to path finding. If you keep files at they are in the `master` branch generating wont even start.
But if you change your path pattern in `wro.xml` replacing path separators from unix to windows style i.e. change  '/' to '\' as it done in the [`windows-separator`](https://github.com/Odomontois/scalatra-coffeescript/tree/windows-separator) branch, you'll receieve following log messages:

```
[info] Using relative Context: /compiled/scripts.css
[info] Processing Group: [scripts] with type [CSS]
[info] Using relative Context: /compiled/scripts.js
[info] Processing Group: [scripts] with type [JS]
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:wro4j for the full output.
[error] (compile:wro4j) ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: No locator is capable of handling uri: \coffee\*.coffee
```